# create a dictionary from the lists based on string match

Tags: python

I have two list of files  as follows:

```
L3 = ['D://carrot_25kg', 'D://banana_5kg', 'D://apple_50kg']
L4 = ['D://box3_5kg-mark', 'D://box1_25kg-dan', 'D://box2_50kg-jack']
```

I needed to group files as follows.

```
result = [['D://carrot_25kg', 'D://box1_25kg-dan'],
          ['D://banana_5kg', 'D://box3_5kg-mark'],
          ['D://apple_50kg', 'D://box1_50kg-jack']] #the order is not important
```

It is to match based on "_xxkg" string. How can I do it guys?

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain    

d = defaultdict(list)

for path in chain(L3, L4):
    suffix = path.split('_')[-1]
    d[suffix].append(path)
```

the result is unexpected.

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'25kg': ['D://carrot_25kg'], '5kg': ['D://banana_5kg'], '50kg': ['D://apple_50kg'], '5kg-mark': ['D://box3_5kg-mark'], '25kg-dan': ['D://box1_25kg-dan'], '50kg-jack': ['D://box2_50kg-jack']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not removing the `-xxxx` part when you form the dictionary key. Use

```
suffix = path.split('_')[-1].split('-')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution (using `re`):

```py
import re
from itertools import chain

L3 = ["D://carrot_25kg", "D://banana_5kg", "D://apple_50kg"]
L4 = ["D://box3_5kg-mark", "D://box1_25kg-dan", "D://box2_50kg-jack"]

pat = re.compile(r"_\d+kg")

out = {}
for v in chain(L3, L4):
    out.setdefault(pat.search(v).group(0), []).append(v)

print(list(out.values()))
```

Prints:

```
[
    ["D://carrot_25kg", "D://box1_25kg-dan"],
    ["D://banana_5kg", "D://box3_5kg-mark"],
    ["D://apple_50kg", "D://box2_50kg-jack"],
]
```

---

[Link to Regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/PvHhMA/1)

Comment: any solution without using re ?

Comment: @mark You can use `str.split`, e.g. how Barmar has shown in his answer. But, in the long run learning basic regex is useful (for other tasks too).